# Grid of subfigures with one caption per row on the left

Tags: tables, graphics, floats, vertical-alignment

I could achieve the following using `figure` and `table`:

[image]

And using some multiline alignment I can align the "captions" (which is actually text) to the center:

[image]

However I'd like to be able to refer to each row using `\ref`, therefore I need each row to be a subfigure, with the caption on the left, without the word "Figure".
How can it be achieved?

This is the code I used so far, using a table:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\par%
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
& RGB & NIR\\
(a) & \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{whatever.jpg} & \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{whatever.jpg}\\
(b) & \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{whatever.jpg} & \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{whatever.jpg}\\
(c) & \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{whatever.jpg} & \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{whatever.jpg}\\
(d) & \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{whatever.jpg} & \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{whatever.jpg}\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{some caption}.}%
\label{fig:fig1}%
\end{figure}
```

I also managed to do a figure of subfigures, but the captions appeared in the bottom.

Comment: Please show the code you've tried so far.

Comment: Added the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following sample code should get you started.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}} % w/ horizontal centering
\usepackage{subcaption} % for 'subfigure' environment
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} r M{0.3\linewidth} M{0.3\linewidth} @{}}
& RGB & NIR\\
\begin{subfigure}{0.05\linewidth} \caption{}\label{subfig:a} \end{subfigure} 
  & \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{whatever.jpg} 
  & \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{whatever.jpg}\\ \addlinespace
\begin{subfigure}{0.05\linewidth} \caption{}\label{subfig:b} \end{subfigure} 
  & \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{whatever.jpg}    
  & \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{whatever.jpg}\\ \addlinespace
\begin{subfigure}{0.05\linewidth} \caption{}\label{subfig:c} \end{subfigure} 
  & \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{whatever.jpg} 
  & \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{whatever.jpg}\\ \addlinespace
\begin{subfigure}{0.05\linewidth} \caption{}\label{subfig:d} \end{subfigure} 
  & \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{whatever.jpg} 
  & \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{whatever.jpg}\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Four rows of graphs}
\label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}

\noindent
Cross-references to subfigures \ref{subfig:a} and \ref{subfig:d}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: To see if I understood your answer (not OP): yo have created a table with three columns, in which the first column has a minimal width and whose only function is to "create" the (a), (b)... as well as the `label` to refer to it. Is that it? It's a very clever solution.

Comment: @Jes - That's exactly right. If I had started from scratch, I might have pursued a different approach. However, I thought it would be useful to build on the the OP's initial code.

Answer (score 5):

The original idea was to use `\subcaption` in the first column, but its baseline is at the top making vertical alignment difficult.  And yes, you can use `\label` with `\tabcaption`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}% or \newcounter{subfigure}[figure]
\usepackage{duckuments}% just for fun
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{v}{>{\sbox0\bgroup}c<{\egroup\raisebox{\dimexpr 0.5\dp0-0.5\ht0}%
 [\dimexpr 0.5\ht0-0.5\dp0+1pt][\dimexpr 0.5\ht0-0.5\dp0+1pt]{\usebox0}}}

\newcommand{\tabcaption}{\refstepcounter{subfigure}(\thesubfigure)}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{vvv}
& RGB & NIR\\
\tabcaption & \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
            & \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-duck}\\
\tabcaption & \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
            & \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-duck}\\
\tabcaption & \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
            & \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-duck}\\
\tabcaption & \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
            & \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{tabular}
\caption{some caption}% note: \caption begins and ends with a \par
\label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 4):

With use of the `floatrow` and `subfig` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[label font=bf, labelformat=simple]{subfig}
\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=center}

\begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.45\textwidth}
    \quad\parbox{0.45\linewidth}{\hfil RGB} \parbox{0.45\linewidth}{\hfil NIR}  
    
    \smallskip 
\sidesubfloat[\label{fig:a}]%
    {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
        \hfil
     \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
    }

\medskip
\sidesubfloat[\label{fig:b}]%
    {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
        \hfil
     \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
    }

\medskip
\sidesubfloat[\label{fig:b}]%
    {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
        \hfil
     \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
    }
    \caption{main caption}
\label{fig:myfigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if I wanted to add text at the bottom of each of the duck figures? I tried including the includegraphics inside the subfloat, but this creates and moves the counter.

Comment: did you mean with your solution? I do not see a table here. However, it works with John Kormylo's solution.

Comment: @user3236841, in image insert (below row of images in `\sidesubfloat`)  rows of  `\parboxes` with desired texts.

Comment: using \parbox, how do I center each text under each duck?

Comment: @user3236841, on the same way as is done in the first "row" with `\parbox`ses.