# make a figure of subfigures of tables of figures

Tags: floats, captions, subfloats, subcaption, subfig

This question builds off of the following:

[grid of subfigures with one caption per row on the left](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586206/grid-of-subfigures-with-one-caption-per-row-on-the-left)

However, what I would like to do is to have a figure with subfigures having similar to these tables. Specifically, I am looking for something like this:

[image]

So, in some sense, put the solution in the link above inside each subfigure. Also, add a caption to each little figure (with some numerical value). Any suggestion as to how I can do this?

Comment: You can put images and text in a tabular.  There are many examples here.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655714/how-to-center-align-subfigures-and-bottom-align-the-captions/655775?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C0.0000#655775 for example.  The only restriction is that `\caption` has to go into a paragraph type column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image can be simple reproduced by expand of code in the question given link to desired number of columns and rows. Using `tabularray` and `adjustbox` packages the table code is simple and short:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}               % for set up page layout
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter,varwidth}   % <===
\usepackage[skip=0.33\baselineskip]{subcaption} 
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}      % <---

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht!]
\adjustboxset{width=\linewidth,
              valign=m
             }

\begin{tblr}{vline{5,8} = {1-5}{solid},
             colsep=2pt,
             colspec = {@{} r *{9}{X[c]} @{}},
             measure = vbox,
             hspan = minimal,
             }
    & coll 1 & coll 2 & coll 3  
                & coll 1 & coll 2 & coll 3  
                            & coll 1 & coll 2 & coll 3          \\
A 1 &   \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck} 
        &   \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck} 
            &  \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck} 
                &   \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck} 
                    &  \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck} 
                        &  \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck} 
                            &   \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck} 
                                &  \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck} 
                                    &  \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck} 
                                                                \\
    & val a11 & val a12 & val a13
                & val b11 & val b12 & val b13
                            & val c11 & val c12 & val c13       \\
A 2  &   \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck} 
        &   \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck} 
            &  \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck} 
                &   \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck} 
                    &  \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck} 
                        &  \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck} 
                            &   \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck} 
                                &  \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck} 
                                    &  \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck} 
                                                                \\
    & val a21 & val a22 & val a23
                & val b21 & val b22 & val b23
                            & val c21 & val c22 & val c23       \\
    &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}    \subcaption{x}  &   &
        &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}    \subcaption{xx} &   &
            &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}    \subcaption{xxx}    &   &   \\
\end{tblr}
\caption{Two rows of graphs}
\label{fig:fig1}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]